# C++ introspection on identifying existence of method signatures

Tags: c++, boost

I'd like to modernise a common technique I use or perhaps over use. It statically checks for method signatures and calls the methods if they exist. My approach predates C++17 by some time FWIW.

Currently, I used Boost's Type traits like `BOOST_TTI_HAS_MEMBER_FUNCTION(event)`

which allows something such as

```cpp
template <typename M, typename E>

static inline typename std::enable_if<
  has_member_function_event<current_t, void, boost::mpl::vector<M &, const E &>>::value
>::type

event(M &mux, S &g, const E &e) {
    auto &node = boost::fusion::at<N>(g);
    node.event(mux, e);
...
```

It works just fine but, you know, it's not the prettiest. Is there a way I might avoid the macros and join the rest of you in the modern world :-)?

Regards,

--Matt. (aka dinosaur)

Comment: [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) will make this easier

Comment: Concepts _should_ make the SFINAE clearer and simpler. Might be time for an upgrade to the head, ta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I have taken Alan Birtles advice and had a look at C++20 concepts for the solution.

Perhaps the use of `std::addressof` is overkill but it makes it almost a one-liner without a macro to define a HasMethodXYZ concept which may then be used for `if constexpr` or for easy SFINAE via a constraint. For example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept HasMethodEvent = requires(T a, void (T::*m)(const std::string&) const) {
  {&a == std::addressof(a)};
  {m = &T::event};
};

struct dude_noway {};

struct dude_no {
  void event(std::string& f) const {}
};

struct dude_yes {
  void event(const std::string& f) const {}
};

template <typename T>
bool perhaps_event() {
  if constexpr (HasMethodEvent<T>) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

template <HasMethodEvent T>
bool perhaps_event_sfinae() {
  return true;
}

template <typename T>
bool perhaps_event_sfinae() {
  return false;
}

//Catch2 test-case check
TEST_CASE("simple event check", "[check_method]") {
  REQUIRE(perhaps_event<dude_yes>());
  REQUIRE_FALSE(perhaps_event<dude_no>());
  REQUIRE_FALSE(perhaps_event<dude_noway>());

  REQUIRE(perhaps_event_sfinae<dude_yes>());
  REQUIRE_FALSE(perhaps_event_sfinae<dude_no>());
  REQUIRE_FALSE(perhaps_event_sfinae<dude_noway>());
}
```

which works OK with clang++-10 using libstdc++-10. For the win, I prefer this to the Boost TTI approach as it co-locates the method signature with the method name as part of the concept rather than using the MPL vector later and it feels simpler.

Thanks, --Matt.

Comment: Nice. One thing I don't like is that it still requires different definitions of "trait helpers" for different members. See the talk that I linked to in the other comment for things that improve on that.

Answer (score 2):

Would simple, direct SFINAE suit your needs?

Here's a test function exercising various member functions, checking for adequate return types and const-correctness as well:

```
template <typename Obj> void exercise(Obj&& obj) {
    if constexpr(has_bar(obj)) {
        std::cout << "called T bar() -> something or void\n";
        obj.bar();
    }
    if constexpr(converts<int>(has_foo(obj))) {
        std::cout << "called int foo() const -> " << obj.foo() << "\n";
    }
    if constexpr(converts<long>(has_foo(obj, "some text"))) {
        std::cout << "called long foo(std::string) -> " << obj.foo("some text") << "\n";
    }
}
```

The `has_bar` implementation is simply:

```
template <typename T>
static constexpr auto has_bar(T&& obj) -> exists<decltype(obj.bar())> { return {}; }
template <typename... T>
static constexpr auto has_bar(T&&...) -> does_not_exist { return {}; }
```

To generically allow for checking signatures and avoid repetitious code, here's a helper macro (obviously optional):

```
#define DEF_HAS_MEMBER(name) \
    template <typename T, typename... Args> \
        static constexpr auto has_##name(T&& obj, Args&&... args)  \
            -> exists<decltype(std::forward<T>(obj).name(std::forward<Args>(args)...))> { return {}; } \
    template <typename... T> \
        static constexpr auto has_##name(T&&...) -> does_not_exist { return {}; } 

DEF_HAS_MEMBER(foo)
DEF_HAS_MEMBER(bar)
```

The `converts` predicate now is an ultra-simple addition:

```
template <typename T, typename R>
    static constexpr auto converts(R) { return std::is_convertible_v<typename R::return_type, T>; }
```

Everything together:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cefa4b5b381778fd)**

```
#include <string>

#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename R> struct exists : std::true_type { using return_type = R; };
struct does_not_exist : std::false_type              { using return_type = void; };

#define DEF_HAS_MEMBER(name) \
    template <typename T, typename... Args> \
        static constexpr auto has_##name(T&& obj, Args&&... args)  \
            -> exists<decltype(std::forward<T>(obj).name(std::forward<Args>(args)...))> { return {}; } \
    template <typename... T> \
        static constexpr auto has_##name(T&&...) -> does_not_exist { return {}; } 

DEF_HAS_MEMBER(foo)
DEF_HAS_MEMBER(bar)

struct Everything {
    int foo(std::string /*unused*/) { return 42; }
    int foo() const { return -1; }
    void bar() {}
};

struct Some {
    int foo() const { return -2; }
};

template <typename T, typename R>
    static constexpr auto converts(R) { return std::is_convertible_v<typename R::return_type, T>; }

template <typename Obj> void exercise(Obj&& obj) {
    std::cout << "===== " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";

    if constexpr(has_bar(obj)) {
        std::cout << "called T bar() -> something or void\n";
        obj.bar();
    }
    if constexpr(converts<int>(has_foo(obj))) {
        std::cout << "called int foo() const -> " << obj.foo() << "\n";
    }
    if constexpr(converts<long>(has_foo(obj, "some text"))) {
        std::cout << "called long foo(std::string) -> " << obj.foo("some text") << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    Everything e;
    Everything const ce;
    Some s;
    Some const cs;

    exercise(s);
    exercise(cs);
    exercise(ce);
    exercise(e);
}
```

Prints

```
===== void exercise(Obj&&) [with Obj = Some&]
called int foo() const -> -2
===== void exercise(Obj&&) [with Obj = const Some&]
called int foo() const -> -2
===== void exercise(Obj&&) [with Obj = const Everything&]
called int foo() const -> -1
===== void exercise(Obj&&) [with Obj = Everything&]
called T bar() -> something or void
called int foo() const -> -1
called long foo(std::string) -> 42
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a nice solution though you end up in a similar place as Boost in that it requires a macro solution to succinctly represent the discrimination by specialisation per method. The ```if constexpr (converts<``` is neat is it avoids the mpl syntax for a more direct object notation which may, however, be more inconvenient for types without handy reification.

I suspect Alan Birtles comment that concepts will improve things is mostly on track.

Comment: Found this to get you somewhere closer https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/9471-vittorio-romeo - it does look nice. Although for member function  calls I think I could do better with my code, because you could go to `OPTO_CALL(foo, memberfunction("bla", std::move(var1)))` reducing repetition. I'm tempted to give it a whirl, but not a lot of time